# Performance/Load testing

Tags: linux, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I wish to do a performance test on my site, simulating thousands of user and find per server capacity limit. The tool I'm using is jmeter and I have prepared a .jmx for the test scenario. But when I try to simulate 1000 of users simultaneously I start to get:

```
<httpSample t="0" lt="0" ts="1338538936990" s="false" lb="VerifyPassword" rc="Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException" rm="Non HTTP response message: Too many open files" tn="LoadConfig 1-901" dt="text" by="1375"/>
```

I think the error is on the client side because of the too many socket connection. If so how can I simulate the case from my local machine? Can I increase the number of open sockets on linux?

Also one thing I discover testing from a single client can give false alarm where the client is the bottleneck and the server works fine. How can I do a performance testing such that I simulate a real life scenario such that I have 10K+ users each have its own CPU/ RAM and then do a performance testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run JMeter from .NET but I think will be the same for your case.

You cannot increase the number of sockets. **You should do a distributed load testing**.
Luckly for you Jmeter has this ability :)

The google term you should look for is distributed JMeter testing or remote JMeter testing. If it happens that you only can use your local machine you might use virtual machines to create several JMeter distributed instances...

Check:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Comment: Where are the logs file formed which determines the detail result. It do not appear on the master nor on the slave?